# How to get complete fullscreen with PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, fullscreen, qgraphicsview

I am having trouble getting a QWidget to real fullscreen in PyQt 4.8 . I took two approaches:

1. Code directly (this works)

   ```
   import sys
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
   import qimage2ndarray as q2n
   import numpy as np
   from scipy.misc.common import lena

   class FullscreenWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent) 
           self.qg = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
           self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
           self.qg.setScene(self.scene)

           # Make window fullscreen and always on top
           self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
           self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

           # set the image (lena)
           qimg = q2n.array2qimage(np.pad(lena(), ((0,0),(0,0)), mode='constant'))        
           pix = QtGui.QPixmap(qimg)        
           self.scene.clear()
           self.scene.addPixmap(pix)  

           self.show()   

   class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
           self.fullscreen = FullscreenWindow()  

           qdw = QtGui.QDesktopWidget()
           screen = qdw.screenGeometry(screen=1)       
           self.fullscreen.setGeometry(screen)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
       winMain = MainWindow(None)
       winMain.show()

       app.exec_()
   ```
2. Designed the window(s) with QtDesigner, having a QWidget with a QGraphicsView, set a QGraphicsScene with my Image. Basically the same code as above but importing the ui-file with the uic module. An image of the  result is appended. I am always getting a gray border that appears to be part of the QWidget.

Why is that? How to get rid of it?

[image: Image of fullscreen with border]

Comment: Why did you incude the code which you say *does* work, but not the code that doesn't? Also, the screenshot you've shown does not look like a fullscreen window - or at least, it does not look anything like the one your code example should produce.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is a bug with `QGraphicsView::fitInView()` they don't care about: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11945

Solution:

```
self.setViewportMargins(-2, -2, -2, -2)
self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
```

`self` is `QGraphicsView` in this case, so you might want to change this.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, its the default style sheet of QWidgets adding that slight border to themselves; in this case `QGraphicsView`.

So, if set the style sheet on your main window through `setStyleSheet`, you can override the css to remove the border--

```
    styleSheetCss="QGraphicsView {border-width: 0px;}"
    self.setStyleSheet(styleSheetCss)
```

In your example-

```
class FullscreenWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.qg = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.qg.setScene(self.scene)

        # Make window fullscreen and always on top
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # set the image (lena)
        qimg = q2n.array2qimage(np.pad(lena(), ((0,0),(0,0)), mode='constant'))        
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap(qimg)        
        self.scene.clear()
        self.scene.addPixmap(pix)  

        styleSheetCss="QGraphicsView {border-width: 0px;}"
        self.setStyleSheet(styleSheetCss)

        self.show()
```

If there is another way to address this problem, I dunno, but this has worked for me.

Side note, you can also string css changes together-

```
styleSheetCss="""
QPushButton {color:#ffffff;background-color:#202020;padding:4px;border:1px solid #303030;}
QMenu {color:#ffffff;background-color:#505050;border:1px solid #282828;}
QMenu::item {color:#ffffff;background-color:#505050;padding:2px;}
QMenu::item:selected {color:#ffffff;background-color:#6c6c6c;padding:2px;}
QSlider {background-color:#323232;}
QScrollBar:vertical {width:10px;color:#ffffff;background-color:#808080;border:1px solid #202020;}"""
self.setStyleSheet(styleSheetCss)
```